# Is there a way to make some piece of code work while textbox has focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textfield

I've been trying to do something with a textbox. I always need to check if the `CaretIndex` property is lower than 3. If it is, I need to set it back to 3. The only way I see is to loop through this code, while textbox has focus.

```
if (textbox.CaretIndex < 3) textbox.CaretIndex = 3;
```

How can I make this piece of code loop while a textbox has focus? There are `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events, but they only work when I click on the textbox.

Comment: `<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"><Setter ...` might possibly do the job, depending on your requirements. Can you divulge what kind of "piece of code" you need to execute, and what "work cyclically" means?

Comment: @EdPlunkett The piece of code is nothing special, just to check CaretIndex so I couldn't make it move to another position. By "work cyclically" I mean looping.

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether you consider it "special" or not. What I'm asking is *what are you trying to do here*? Why that event? Can you find some *other* event that'll serve the same purpose? Must it be a mouse button? Specialness is not of the essence. I'm assuming the code had some purpose, and you had some reason to use that event instead of some other event.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ok. When I click on textbox, I always need to check if the CaretIndex in this textbox is larger than 3. If it's lower, I need to set it back to 3. I can't use TextChanged, because I can also move the Caret with arrow keys and mouse. That's why I need looping.

Comment: Did you try the `SelectionChanged` event? CaretIndex can't change without the selection changing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, it works almost the same as `TextChanged`.

Comment: It does exactly what you claim you want. It's raised when the selection changes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, I made the if condition `textbox.CaretIndex > 3`. Yes, it works wonderful. Thank you very much! You may rewrite your comment to an answer if you want.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual requirements you have regarding CaretIndex, and show what you tried to achieve that. That's why you were getting downvotes, I suspect.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited. Though I've been on SE long enough, I still can't 
adapt to SO style )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you really just need to keep an eye on `CaretIndex`. The easiest way to do that is handle the TextBox's `SelectionChanged` event: The caret is one end of the selection, and it's the end that can change. Anything anybody does to change the caret position, with mouse or keyboard, will change the selection.

```
private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (textbox.CaretIndex < 3) 
        textbox.CaretIndex = 3;
}
```

```
<TextBox SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```